# In server-client poker game, what is the best way to notify user about user's turn when app is in background

Tags: ios, sockets, poker

I am developing server-client model poker game, In which all game logic handling by server. I have a situation, when user tap home button in the middle of the game suppose 4 players playing a poker game. and the iPhone user tap home button, So app goes to background due to this no code is running and app is unable to get server messages.

I want to notify user when its turn comes to play on poker game. I would like to know the best possible ways to do this

thanks

Comment: Did you try push notifications?

Comment: No, I am confuse between push notification and apple background fetching. should i use push notification or apple background fetching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push Notifications are definitely the way to go for this!

Your situations requires that the iOS app gets notified when it's the user's turn. Since the server is the one knowing precisely when it's a user's turn, it is also the best instance to also notify that user.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'll go with push notification

Comment: sure, just don't forget to tick the green checkmark to mark the question as answered :)